# Save web pages with all their images, CSS, and other resources

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, caching, html

I need to download a few web pages for later usee in my application, and I can't find an easy way to accomplish this task. I would prefer a solution where I don't need to parse the HTML to get the URLs of the images and other resources, but rather download these somehow automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK guys, here is my solution:

1. created my own cache object, derived from NSURLCache
2. added to it a "state" enum variable, with the possible states of: SAVING, LOADING, NOTHING
3. overwritten cachedResponseForRequest to do things according to the state
4. SAVING: created a NSMutableDictionary to store every download request
5. Downloaded the file in the request to a flat file, added the path to the file to the dictionary as an object, with the URL as the key
6. LOADING: used this dictionary as they did in this example to load back the stored content: http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/substituting-local-data-for-remote.html
7. set my cache object as the shared cache object using [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:myCacheObject];

After this, when I want to save something I set the cache's state to SAVING, and load a request to an UIWebView. After this I set the state back to LOADING, load a request to an UIWebView, and if I stored my request previously, my cache will load it from the disk.

Answer (score 0):

I think ASIHTTPRequest framework can be useful for you - try [ASIWebPageRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest) and see if it supports all features you need.

Comment: Thanks, the functionality of ASIHTTPRequest would be good, but my colleagues tested it before, and it was too slow, and made too many faulty web pages. We need something similar like this, but more reliable.

Comment: @Kompi: I don't any other solution and it seems to that if ASIWebPageRequest is too slow, you'll probably need to write own one. Please post your solution once you choose it. Thanks!